# conditional match and count with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, match

Imagine my friends are recommending me some cars depending on my budget. I want to determine, for each budget, the number of times when all friends recommend the same make as well as the number of times when all friends recommend the same make and model.

```
budget <- c(rep(c("broke", "modest", "dreaming"), each = 3), rep("broke", 3))
friend <- (rep(c("mark", "mary", "monelle"), 4))
make <- c(rep("ford", 3), rep("honda", 3), "porche", rep("bmw",2), rep("bicycle", 3))
model <- c(rep("fiesta", 3), rep("civic", 2), "tacoma", "911", "i3", "Z4", rep("used", 3))

df <- data.frame(budget, friend, make, model)

     budget  friend    make  model
1     broke    mark    ford fiesta
2     broke    mary    ford fiesta
3     broke monelle    ford fiesta
4    modest    mark   honda  civic
5    modest    mary   honda  civic
6    modest monelle   honda tacoma
7  dreaming    mark  porche    911
8  dreaming    mary     bmw     i3
9  dreaming monelle     bmw     Z4
10    broke    mark bicycle   used
11    broke    mary bicycle   used
12    broke monelle bicycle   used
```

Desired Output -

```
budget matchMake matchMake+Model
broke      2     2 
modest     1     0
dreaming   0     0
```

Comment: Do add desired output as well for the updated example.

Comment: Hopefully this makes sense? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your expected result does not follow from your reprex input - if you're looking for more answers, make sure your reprex makes sense from end-to-end. As for question, look into `dplyr::count`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What do you mean "how often my friends are telling me to purchase the same car"? If someone tells you to buy the same make once, is that 0 or 1? If they told you twice, is it 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with `dplyr`.

```
df %>% 
  spread(friend, model) %>% 
  mutate(
    matchMake = apply(.[3:5], 1, function(x) !anyNA(x)),
    matchMake_Model = apply(.[3:5], 1, function(x) all(x[1] == x))
  ) %>% 
  group_by(budget) %>% 
  summarise(
    matchMake = sum(matchMake, na.rm = T),
    matchMake_Model = sum(matchMake_Model, na.rm = T)
  ) 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  budget   matchMake matchMake_Model
  <fct>        <int>           <int>
1 broke            2               2
2 dreaming         0               0
3 modest           1               0
```

Comment: Very helpful. I wanted the numeric because we could imagine the scenario where friends recommend > 1 car for each budget type. Then I'm trying to calculate how often, versus just the T/F per budget... I updated the question to extend the reprex:

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using plyr's split-apply-combine (splitting on variable "budget") and using `count` to test how many times the same make or make/model is specified

```
ddply(df, .(budget), function(df_budget) 
      c(matchMake = sum(count(df_budget, "make")$freq > 1), 
        matchMakeModel = sum(count(df_budget, c("make", "model"))$freq > 1)))
```